# .NET OAuth2 Sign-on Google server-side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, google-api, google-oauth

I was read the documentation about implementing external login (google)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

It's work perfect by with Identity,but due to some reason I can't use that approach and I am wondering how I can get granted fields (like email and name) in more manual  way.

Like this :
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

I need something similar, but from server side.

Ive Added this to my Startup.cs

```
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Google";
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddGoogle("Google", googleOptions =>
        {
            googleOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
            googleOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
        });
```

This Action who open Google login window

```
        string localeToken = (string)HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["clientId"];

        var redirectUrl = Url.Action("SignInCallback", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = $"SO-{localeToken}/Account/GoogleLogin" });

        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties? properties =
            new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties();
        //_signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);

        properties.RedirectUri = redirectUrl;

        ChallengeResult challengeResult = new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);

        return challengeResult;
```

After this action occur redirect to SignInCallback, everething looks good but i dont know what i need to do further, i dont know where and how i can get user data, like id or email so i can create user with that data manually without identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Ultimate guide for what i was needed :

https://blog.rashik.com.np/adding-google-authentication-in-net-core-application-without-identity/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).